# Created Outlook event timespans differs in SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar, outlook, events

i have the following Problem. 
When I create an Outlook Event and Sync it to the SharePoint calendar the Event Times differs.

For Example. 
When I create a Event from 8-10 o clock. The SharePoint displays the Event from 9-11 o clock.

I tried to set all the timezones to the German Timezone. But it didn't solve the problem.

note:
The events will be created only in outlook, not by code or s.th.

Comment: Was this solved? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you set the time zones?

You need to get the time zones correct on all computers involved (both client, and in your SharePoint farm).

Also the time zone in Outlook needs to be correct, check:

> Tools --> Options --> Preferences --> Calendar Options --> Time Zone

Also make sure that you tick in the box for automatic Daylight Saving Time adjustments